# Calculus of variation problem with integral product constraint

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I want to find the extrema of the functional,

$$
J[y] =\int^1_0 L(x, y(x)) \ \text{d} x
$$

in the space of continuous functions $C[0, 1]$, subject to the constraint,

$$
 \int^1_0 \left(y(x) - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \text{d} x \ \times 
 \int^1_0 y(t) \ \text{d} t  = 1
$$

I know how to derive the Euler-Lagrange equation for the case in which the constraint is a simple integral of the form

$$
\int^1_0 M(t, y(t), y^\prime(t)) \ \text{d} t = c
$$

but I could not find any reference on a constraint with a product of integrals, as is my case.

Do you know of any reference book I could consult on this or could you point me in the right directions to derive the EL equation myself?

Comment: Is the explicit form of $L$ given?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give it any explicit form. I just know that it does not depend on $y^\prime$(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. OP's variational problem is of the form
   $$ J[y]~=~\int_0^1 \! \mathrm{d}x~L(x,y(x),\ldots) \tag{1}$$
   with the constraint
   $$F[y]G[y]~=~1,\tag{2}$$
   where
   $$ F[y]~=~\int_0^1 \! \mathrm{d}x~f(x,y(x),\ldots) \tag{3}$$
   and
   $$ G[y]~=~\int_0^1 \! \mathrm{d}x~g(x,y(x),\ldots) \tag{4}$$
   are functionals.
2. Introduce [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) $\lambda$ and an extended functional
   $$\widetilde{J}[y,\lambda]~=~J[y]+\lambda(F[y]G[y]-1).\tag{5} $$
   Provided adequate boundary conditions, the Euler-Lagrange equation takes the form
   $$0~=~\frac{\delta\widetilde{J}[y,\lambda]}{\delta y(x)}~=~\frac{\delta J[y]}{\delta y(x)}+\lambda(\frac{\delta F[y]}{\delta y(x)}G[y] + F[y]\frac{\delta G[y]}{\delta y(x)}).\tag{6} $$
3. To solve eq. (6) replace $F[y],G[y]$ with 2 parameters $F^{\ast}, G^{\ast}\in \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
   $$0~=~\frac{\delta J[y]}{\delta y(x)}+\lambda(\frac{\delta F[y]}{\delta y(x)}G^{\ast} + F^{\ast}\frac{\delta G[y]}{\delta y(x)}).\tag{7} $$
   Eq. (7) is an equation for $y$ as a function of 3 external parameters $\lambda, F^{\ast}, G^{\ast}$.
4. Finally, determine possible $\lambda,F^{\ast}, G^{\ast}$ by the self-consistency conditions
   $$ F[y]~=~F^{\ast}, \qquad  G[y]~=~G^{\ast}, \tag{9} $$
   and the constraint (2).